# CSS selector (id contains part of text)

Tags: css, css-selectors, webdriver

I have a question.
I have elements something like this:

`<a>` element with id = someGenerated Some:Same:0:name

`<a>` element with id = someGenerated Some:Same:0:surname

`<a>` element with id = someGenerated Some:Same:1:name

`<a>` element with id = someGenerated Some:Same:1:surname

I need CSS selector to get names. The problem is that I don't know how to get it.
I tried `a[id*='Some:Same']` - it returned all `<a>` elements. After I can get elements which id ends with name. But I don't like this idea. I think that it can be done with some other selector.

Comment: Could you please add some real examples of `<a>` tags that you want to select and those that you do not want. It will be easier to help seeing the real code.

Comment: I can't add real example, because of confidential policy :(

Comment: But I can explain it in other way. Id attributes contains next: some generated characters + some static characters + :elementIndexInTable: + column name in table

Comment: And what are the criteria for those you want?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Try this:

```
a[id*='Some:Same'][id$='name']
```

This will get you all `a` elements with id containing

> Some:Same

and have the id ending in

> name

Comment: Well, id* didn't work for me and it said can't be evaluated to a web element. I used it to find iframe which has id like `<constant><variable><constant>` name. `//driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id*,'FrameID')]")).size();` where FrameID is beginning part. Anyways, `//a[contains(@id,'Some:Same') and contains(@id,'name')]` did the trick for me. So +1 to you mate.

Comment: You should remove the XPath selector from this answer, it's not adding anything and is only muddying the waters

Comment: @CosminO Do you need the `*` next to `id`?

Comment: @cokedude  the *= operator means that it must contain at least the value after the operator. It works in conjunction with the second condition that it must end with something else by using the operator $=   
See this for an in depth explanation https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Short answer. The * is not next to id, it is next to = and it forms an operator with special meaning

Answer (score 62):

```
<div id='element_123_wrapper_text'>My sample DIV</div>
```

The Operator **^** - Match elements that starts with given value

```
div[id^="element_123"] {

}
```

The Operator $ - Match elements that ends with given value

```
div[id$="wrapper_text"] {

}
```

The Operator * - Match elements that have an attribute containing a given value

```
div[id*="123_wrapper"] {

}
```

Answer (score 7):

The only selector I see is `a[id$="name"]` (all links with id finishing by "name") but it's not as restrictive as it should.