# Shortening html IDs to use in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there any way to shorten a HTML element tag like this:

```
<input id=ctl00_ctl32_g_9bd32d9e_a30e_48f8_af0e_4c4b7e8ba1f5_createSuggestion>
```

In CSS so that I don't have to reference the entire thing and just use the createSuggestion  part of it like this:

```
input createSuggestion{
margin-left:10%;
}
```

For instance, when producing a SQL query, sometimes a 'like %createSuggestion' would be used.
Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS select elements with partial id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533484/css-select-elements-with-partial-id)

Comment: Why not actually apply the appropriate class to the input element, assuming you have control of the markup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could achieve that by [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) as follows:

```css
input[id$="createSuggestion"] {
    margin-left: 10%;
}
```

> **[6.3.2. Substring matching attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings)**
>
> `[att$=val]` Represents an element with the att attribute whose value
>   ends with the suffix "val". If "val" is the empty string then the
>   selector does not represent anything.

Comment: when using a div tag what does the coding become? eg. div id=..pComment have tried using div[id$..] and #pComment

Comment: @matt `div[id$="pComment"]` - **[Example](http://jsbin.com/puququ/1/edit?html,css,output)**.

Answer (score 2):

Add `ClientIdMode="Static"` in your server-side control to prevent that entirely.