# Locating icons in selenium table

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

How to locate icons in a table which has as **id** in html code are based on "delete_*number*" , "edit_*number*" and the *number* is the serial number in selenium using python and without using xpath.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `find_elements_by_css_selector` with [partial attribute selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533484/css-select-elements-with-partial-id).

Something like:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[id^="delete_"]')
```