# Is an attribute selector for the ID attribute less specific than an ID selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

What do I need to do to give the `[id^=value]` selector the same specificity as a regular ID, and why isn't it equal or greater already? *(considering that I gave it `html` as well)*

```css
html div[id^="blue"] {
    background-color: blue
}

#blue4 {
    background-color: red
}
```

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/bjwe6yr0/1/

Comment: This is a matter of how CSS is designed. [A ID selector (#) has a higher specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than class and attribute selectors.

Comment: So, though it's selecting IDs, it's not actually being credited as an ID? *And I'm reviewing your link now*

Comment: `div[id^="blue"]` is an attribute selector. you could also address `[data-something]` in the same fashion. Also if you address the id in your example, you do not use the dedicated id selector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An attribute selector will always be less specific than an ID selector; its specificity value does not change based on the attribute name. Selectors only maps specific attribute names to class selectors and ID selectors; an attribute selector is a generic concept and does not contain any such mappings.

The *only* way for a complex selector to have ID specificity is if it contains one or more ID selectors. Implementation limits aside, it is theoretically not possible to override even a single ID selector with any number of attribute selectors or any other type of simple selector.

Here is how your two selectors compare:

```css
/* 1 attribute, 2 types -> specificity = 0-1-2 */
html div[id^="blue"] {
    background-color: blue
}

/* 1 ID                 -> specificity = 1-0-0 */
#blue4 {
    background-color: red
}
```

Even the addition of `html` doesn't help because it's just a type selector. Change it to `:root` and you get a pseudo-class which is equally specific to an attribute selector, and thus *still* less specific than an ID.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider the `not()` selector in order to append a random ID and you will then have a higher or the same specifity since the specifity of `not()` is equal to the specifity of the selector inside it:

```css
html body div[id^="blue"]:not(#randomID) {
  background-color: blue
}

#blue4 {
  background-color: red
}

div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px
}
```

```html
<div id="blue1"></div>
<div id="blue2"></div>
<div id="blue3"></div>
<div id="blue4"></div>
```

Comment: Should be the correct answer because it solves the problem.