# background-color not overwriting fully defined background property

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am making a toolbar menu of three elements, which should have the same styling except for different background images that serve as icons.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="menu-handheld">
    <a href="page.php?stuff=things" id="menu-handheld-tab-start">Start</a>
    <a href="page.php?stuff=things" id="menu-handheld-tab-trends">Trends</a>
    <a href="page.php?stuff=things" id="menu-handheld-tab-recent">Recent</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#menu-handheld {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3.8rem;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}

#menu-handheld-tab-start { background: rgb(0, 51, 51) no-repeat 50% 0.5rem/2rem url(img/icons/start.svg) }
#menu-handheld-tab-trends { background: rgb(0, 51, 51) no-repeat 50% 0.5rem/2rem url(img/icons/trends.svg) }
#menu-handheld-tab-recent { background: rgb(0, 51, 51) no-repeat 50% 0.5rem/2rem url(img/icons/recent.svg) }

[id|=menu-handheld-tab], [id|=menu-handheld-tab]:visited { /* common CSS */
    display: block;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 33.33333%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 2.5rem;
    color: rgb(102, 153, 153);
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-family: treme-extra-light;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    transition: background 0.3s ease;
}

[id|=menu-handheld-tab]:active, [id|=menu-handheld-tab]:hover {
    background-color: rgb(102, 153, 153); /* this does not work */
    color: rgb(0, 51, 51); /* this works fine */
}
```

As I commented in the code, the :hover/:active transition works fine on the text color, but not at all on the background-color. I believe this is an issue with the fully written out background properties I am using for each element separately, because I had the same problem when I tried to define the background property in the common CSS and only use background-image in the separate selectors.

What am I doing wrong here? Why does background-color, or background-anything for that matter, fail to overwrite the background property? I realize I may fix my problem by defining another set of three #menu-handheld-tab-stuff {} selectors and writing out a new full background definition, but that's not a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color declaration takes effect because there are no existing color declarations to override.

The background-color declaration does not take effect because ID selectors are more specific than attribute selectors and pseudo-classes combined. This is because an attribute selector is always less specific than an ID selector, [even when that attribute selector is specific to the id attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868028/is-an-attribute-selector-for-the-id-attribute-less-specific-than-an-id-selector/32868338#32868338). Each of your rules containing an ID selector therefore retains its background shorthand declaration, including its color value.

Normally, working around this would involve specificity hacks or even using `!important`, but in this specific case, you should be able to get away with adding `#menu-handheld` to your selectors (and, optionally, replacing the attribute selectors with the more simple `a` type selectors since there are no other children of `#menu-handheld`):

```
#menu-handheld a:active, #menu-handheld a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(102, 153, 153);
    color: rgb(0, 51, 51);
}
```

(While you're at it, for the sake of consistency I recommend doing the same with the previous rule.)