# css selectors - how to select div#my_id_n

Tags: css, css-selectors

Given I have

```
div#my_id_1
div#my_id_2
div#my_id_3
```

How do I write a CSS selector that matches all `div`s with id `my_id_n`?

With regex if I want to match `my_id_n` I can do `/my_id_\d+/` to match `my_id_n`. What's the equivalent here?

Comment: See also [CSS selector (id contains part of text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155833/css-selector-id-contains-part-of-text)

Comment: Do note the advice on [the answer to CSS select elements with partial id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13533508) (from [BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock)): "...why not add a common class to each group of elements and select by that class to make things simpler?"

Comment: @TylerH make that an answer and I'll pick it.

Comment: @DavidWest It's a duplicate, so the appropriate system action is what has already happened; the question is closed so that it can serve to point others toward that Q&A set.