# How do i Remove Range Number ID Elements from page?

Tags: css, freshdesk

Im using Freshdesk System and i have notice that it has columns that i dont use.
So, with the Styler Classic extension on Chrome i wanted to hide or remove the columns that i dont use.

[image]

```
<div id="ember1955" class="ember-view" data-identifyelement="156">
<div data-test-id="tkt-properties-name" data-identifyelement="157">
 <div id="ember1956" class="input ember-view" data-identifyelement="158"> <label for="customFields.name_ember1956" class="label-field " data-identifyelement="159">Name</label>

    <input data-test-text-field="customFields.name" type="text" name="customFields.name" autocomplete="off" id="customFields.name_ember1956" class="ember-text-field ember-view" data-identifyelement="160">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

As you can see we have here the **data-test-id** field named **tkt-properties-name**

When i try to use that css code:

```
div#tkt-properties-name {display: none; visibility: hidden;}
```

or

```
#tkt-properties-name {display: none; visibility: hidden;}
```

But nothing was changed.

Also, they have the **`emberxxxx`** id's that allways change.
I try to use:

```
#ember^ {display: none; visibility: hidden;}
```

or attribute selector:

```
#[data-test-id="tkt-properties-name"] {display: none; visibility: hidden;}
```

But nothing was changed.

How do i remove that elements that based on "emberxxxx" numbers range?

Comment: `#` before the attribute selector is nonsense, you want `[data-test-id="tkt-properties-name"]`

Comment: Allright. How do you use it?

Comment: And `#ember^` would be wrong as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533484/css-select-elements-with-partial-id

Comment: Ok. so is the `div[data-test-id^="ember_"]` or `div[id^="ember_"]` will work? If not, what do you suggest?

Comment: Nevermind. got it myself

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
div[data-test-id^="tkt-properties-name"] {display: none; visibility: hidden;}
```

And now it is working!