# Access to a document in a frame. Frontend Test Automation

Tags: html, iframe, frontend, automated-tests, playwright

## In the test case, you need to fill input[id="card"], which is located inside the iframe. You must use Playwright.

In [Playwright documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/frames) there is a *frame()* method that returns an iframe that matches the specified criteria. You must pass 1 parameter: **name attribute value** or **URL**.

The solution should be simple:

```
const myFrame = page.frame('element382');
await myFrame?.locator('input[id="card"]').fill('0123456789');
```

But, every time the page is refreshed, my name attribute value and my url address dynamically change - **the number 382 is replaced with another**.

(P.S. the src link is fictitious, but the point is that the id or name value is in the link)

```
<iframe id="element382" name="element382" src="https://something/link/&element382">
...
   <input id="card">
...
</iframe>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I select elements in CSS by partial ID value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533484/how-can-i-select-elements-in-css-by-partial-id-value)

Answer (score 0):

The [frame method](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-frame) supports regex in url, so you can eg. do this to accept any number in the url:

```js
const myFrame = page.frame(url: {/https:\/\/something\/link\/&element\d*/});
```