# Allow javascript to work on div with any number appended to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random, numbers

I have a small bit of jquery that applies the jquery-ui accordian to an array of divs.

The divs are generated dynamically and each one needs to have a unique ID. I have successfully generated unique IDs for divs with each one having a different number at the end. Now I would like the jquery to be flexible enough to handle any of the divs no matter what number is at the end. All the divs have IDs with the naming convention "activity-accordion123" or "activity-accordian+number"

Here is the code I am using currently for the divs that have already been generated:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#activity-accordion408,#activity-accordion410,#activity-accordion415,#activity-accordion428,#activity-accordion439,#activity-accordion427" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true,
heightStyle: "content",
active: false,
header: "h3",
navigation: true
    }); 
  });
```

I would like to change this javascript so that it will work with any div that has the ID of "activity-accordion+any number". Is this possible?

Comment: This post probably answers it best:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376431/wildcards-in-jquery-selectors

Comment: Can you also add a class which is the same for all divs? You could then select multiple divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ID attribute selector wildcard 'start with' like that:

```
$('div[id^="activity-accordion"]').accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: "content",
    active: false,
    header: "h3",
    navigation: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this css selector: `*=`

```
$(function() {
    $( "[id*='activity-accordion']" ).accordion({
         collapsible: true,
         heightStyle: "content",
         active: false,
         header: "h3",
         navigation: true
    }); 
});
```

Comment: '*=' means contains not start with

Comment: @zladuric that doesn't matter; it's jQuery so it'll work wherever the library works.

Comment: @roasted see this question's accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155833/css-selector-id-contains-part-of-text

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui your answer would work too but i was thinking OP wants ID starting with some string, not containing some string

Comment: No, using your selector you will match element with ID `something-activity-accordion` too

Answer (score 1):

you could select them like this:

```
$("div[id^='activity-accordion'"])
```

Selects all div, that starts with **activity-accordion**

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason that you can not simply have each div possess an "activity-accordion" class? Classes are useful to style/manipulate multiple similar elements. You can then use `$('.activity-accordion')` to select all such elements.

Comment: Yes I thought of that but the jquery-ui accordion, if to be repeated on one page, needs to be applied to divs with unique IDs/Classes. As far as I could understand.

Answer (score 0):

use a class would be more didactic and correct to do

```
$(function() {
    $( ".accordions" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true,
heightStyle: "content",
active: false,
header: "h3",
navigation: true
    }); 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

To match all `<div>`s, with an `id` of the pattern `activity-accordion<number>`, you can use:

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return /activity\-accordion\d+/.test(this.id);
}).accordion({
    ...
});
```