# How to use variable CSS selector

Tags: javascript, css, selector

Does anyone know how I can use a variable CSS selector? For example, I want my CSS to grab a table `id` attribute that's variable... something like:

```
<table id="table_1">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table id="table_2">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table id="table_3">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now I want to grab the tables by their `id`:

```
table#[INSERT VARIABLE TABLE ID HERE]{ 
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Agenda-Light, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100; 
  background: #333; color: #fff;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  border-radius: 5px; 
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155833/css-selector-id-contains-part-of-text

Comment: For this specific example: `table[id^=table_]` will select all `<table>` elements with an `id` attribute that starts with string `"table_"`.

Comment: No, this isn't possible, CSS doesn't have variables. You would need to make this a class and then vary which table has the class using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all tables have same css you could use a class instead of id.

It is not possible to iterate or do other kind of logic in css. To use variables you could use css pre processors like sass or less, but you would have to define every variable "by hand".