# Select div with unknown id in name

Tags: css

I have div named **#mobile_div_111X222X333-99**, **111X222X333** is question id which can change. I have lots of questions but I want to select every div that contains **#mobile_div_{*any_ID*}-99** is it anyway to do that with css only?

Comment: The same question asked, check the link below [CSS selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155833/css-selector-id-contains-part-of-text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Althought CSS does not support regular expression query selector, with your case, we can select `div` that has `id` attribute starts with `mobile_div_` and ends with `-99`

```
div[id^="mobile_div_"][id$="-99"] {
    // your style
}
```

We use two CSS3 selectors here:

`^=` starts with

`$=` ends with

Refs:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_end.asp

Comment: Thank you works like a butter 

Answer (score 1):

You can use prefix attribute selectors with `[x^=y]`, i.e. `[id^=mobile_div_]`.

If that's not specific enough, you can stack a suffix attribute selector on top, using the syntax `[x$=y]`, i.e. `[id$=-99]`, for a complete selector of `[id^=mobile_div_][id$=-99]`. Note the lack of a space between the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use is like this -

HTML

```
<div id="abc-123">
  <h1>helo</h1>
</div>
<div id="123-xyz">
  <h1>helo</h1>
</div>
<div id="mobile_div_a-99">
  <h1>helo</h1>
</div>
<div id="mobile_div_b-11">
  <h1>helo</h1>
</div>
<div id="mobile_div_c-99">
  <h1>helo</h1>
</div>
```

The (^) is used for "starting with" and ($) is used for "ending with".

```
[id^="abc"]{
  color:blue;
}

[id$="xyz"]{
  color:green;
}

[id^="mobile_div_"][id$='-99']{
background-color:red;  
}
```

if id='abc-xyz', since CSS is Cascading Style Sheets (ie: top to bottom approach ) , the text color will be green.