# How to select html elements where id contains

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How do I go about selecting html elements that the id contains a given string? would querySelectorAll accomplish this? I know I can select classes, id's, attributes etc... with querySelectorAll,

Just not sure the correct approach for what I need to do

Here is some code that I would like to only get the elements where the id contains Home

```
<div id="ContactContainer>
    <input class="form-control input-sm clear" is-required="false" validate-number="" minlength="1" maxlength="3" id="txtCustomerWorkAreaCode" placeholder="9999">
    <input class="form-control input-sm clear" is-required="false" validate-number="" minlength="1" maxlength="3" id="txtCustomerWorkExchange" placeholder="9999">
    <input class="form-control input-sm clear" is-required="false" validate-number="" minlength="4" maxlength="4" id="txtCustomerWorkSuffix" placeholder="9999">


    <input class="form-control input-sm clear" is-required="false" validate-number="" minlength="1" maxlength="3" id="txtCustomerHomeAreaCode" placeholder="9999">
    <input class="form-control input-sm clear" is-required="false" validate-number="" minlength="1" maxlength="3" id="txtCustomerHomeExchange" placeholder="9999">
    <input class="form-control input-sm clear" is-required="false" validate-number="" minlength="4" maxlength="4" id="txtCustomerHomeSuffix" placeholder="9999">


    <input class="form-control input-sm clear" is-required="false" validate-number="" minlength="1" maxlength="3" id="txtCustomerMobileAreaCode" placeholder="9999">
    <input class="form-control input-sm clear" is-required="false" validate-number="" minlength="1" maxlength="3" id="txtCustomerMobileExchange" placeholder="9999">
    <input class="form-control input-sm clear" is-required="false" validate-number="" minlength="4" maxlength="4" id="txtCustomerMobileSuffix" placeholder="9999">
</div>
```

Comment: imo you'd be better off adding classes for that.

Comment: Get the parent container with `document.querySelectorAll('#ContactContainer')`, then get the children of this element, iterate through the children and `forEach` element if the Id is equal to what you want then push it to an array or do whatever you want with it.

Comment: This might help: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155833/css-selector-id-contains-part-of-text#answer-12157322

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use wildcard selectors as shown below to match a partial attribute tag, including id.

```
document.querySelector('[id*="MobileAreaCode"]');
```

If you want more than one element to be returned use querySelectorAll.

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id*="Mobile"]');
```

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something, but that works for the way you are proposing, but how do i find the elements if they contain a string, such as Home or Mobile. Maybe I not understanding correctly?

Comment: Contain a string inside the id attribute?  If you're looking for multiple elements which contain part of a string in the ID attribute (or any other attribute) I updated my answer to show how.

Comment: Yes...So with this txtCustomerHomeAreaCode, I want to find the elements where the id contains Home etc...

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. The only issue i have now is that those elements are in divs that contain the same text in its id, so now i just got to find out how to just get the inputs. Thanks for putting on the right path

Comment: Just figured it out