# scrapy returning an empty object

Tags: python, scrapy, css-selectors, web-crawler

i am using css selector and continually get a response with empty values. Here is the code.

```
import scrapy 

class WebSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'activities'
start_urls = [
    'http://capetown.travel/events/'
]


def parse(self, response):
    all_div_activities = response.css("div.tribe-events-content")#gdlr-core-pbf-column gdlr-core-column-60 gdlr-core-column-first
    title = all_div_activities.css("h2.tribe-events-list-event-title::text").extract()#gdlr-core-text-box-item-content
    price = all_div_activities.css(".span.ticket-cost::text").extract()
    details = all_div_activities.css(".p::text").extract()
    yield {
        'title':title,
        'price':price,
        'details':details
    }
```

Comment: Hi, may I know what is the expected output?

Comment: @balandongiv {'title': [Stellenbosch on Stage: Libertas Choir virtual concert ], 'price': [ZAR100], 'details': [The world-class Libertas Choir is set to perform a live virtual concert on Saturday, 11 July which will allow audience members to watch the exclusive performance in the comfort of their own homes. The show is the first of three events hosted in association with Visit Stellenbosch as Stellenbosch on Stage, an initiative displaying unity and solidarity. All proceeds are in aid of Stellenbosch Unite, a collaboration providing support to vulnerable communities during the...]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you're looking to select all events but that output will be a list and you can't select the title etc using extract() with a list as you are trying to do.

This is why you're not getting the data you want. You will need to use a for loop to loop over each event on the page in your case looping over `all_div_activities`.

### Code for Script

```
def parse(self,response):
    all_div_activities = response.css('div.tribe-events-event-content')
    for a in all_div_activities:
        title = a.css('a.tribe-event-url::text').get()

        if a.css('span.ticket-cost::text'):
            price = a.css('span.ticket-cost::text').get()
        else: 
            price = 'No price'

        details = a.css('div[class*="tribe-events-list-event-description"] > p::text').get()

        yield { 
               'title':title.strip(),
                'price':price,
                'details':details
              }
```

Notes

1. Using an if statement for price because there were elements that had no price at all and so inputting some information is a good idea.
2. Using strip() on title when yielding the dictionary as the title had space and \n attached.

### Advice

As a minor point, Scrapy suggests using get() and getall() methods rather than extract_first() and extract(). With extract() its not always possible to know the output is going to be a list or not, in this case the output I got was a list. This is why scrapy docs suggests using get() instead. It's also abit more compact. With get() you will always get a string. This also meant that I could strip newlines and space with the title as you can see in the above code.

Another tip would be if the class attribute is quite long, use a *= selector as long as the partial attribute you select provides a unique result to the data you want. See here for abit more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155833/css-selector-id-contains-part-of-text).

Using items instead of yielding a dictionary may be better in the longrun, as you can set default values for data that in some events on the page you're scraping  and other events it's not. You have to do this through a pipeline (again if you don't understand this then don't worry). See the docs for items and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6lOVwigsNA) for abit more on items.

Comment: the code runs when is remove .strip() , but there is another issue where title: returns none and price: No Price everywhere @AaronS

Comment: Can you post the entire code of the script ? Because My script is working, with strip() and all titles are there. I've also just re-copied my own SO entry into a blank script and it works too.

Comment: where can i attach it its too long fr this comment section

Comment: https://pastebin.com/, Create a new paste and copy the link. As I have said, I've just copied the function I typed in SO into a blank script and it seems to be running, so it's maybe something minor in your own code/setup of scrapy.

Comment: Also looking at the dataset abit more closely there's some unicode being outputted. Scrapy automatically encodes in unicode when the output is json, converting to utf-8 will fix the characters that are coming out as unicode. If you add one line down from start_urls = [] in your script.
custom_settings = {'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8'} 
This will fix this

Comment: You've put 
details = a.css("div[class*='tribe-events-list-event-description'] > p::text").get()
                yield {
                        'title':title.strip(),
                        'price':price,
                        'details':details

Inside the else statement, needs to be taken outside that if statement. Just need to move it by 4 spaces back to be on the same line spacing as title.

Comment: Could you tick my answer as the accepted answer ? The tick at the left side of my post. That would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my one. Hope it will help you.

```
for item in response.css('div.tribe-events-event-content'): 
    print(item.css('a.tribe-event-url::text').get()) 
    print(item.css('span.ticket-cost::text').get()) 
    print(item.css('p::text').get())
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some steps to get your code fixed

- When use period before name that represents the element's class name NOT HTML tag itself.. So change `.span.ticket-cost::text` --> `span.ticket-cost::text`
  Also `.p::text` --> `p::text`.
- Obviously you trying to get a string so use `get()` method instead of   `extract()` method which is return a list.
- Make sure to use `>` when the desired text is inside the child element of the element you've select.
- Finally here is a CSS Selector Reference https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp